# Create an object based on user interaction

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to create a new object based on user input. I have been googling this for ages and can't find a solution. Essentially I want my program to spit out records already contained in the program and then offer the user an option to add a new record using a switch statement. So far I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RetailItemDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Define the variables
        String ItemDescription;
        int ItemUnits;
        double ItemPrice;


        //create scanner class
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //create new objects

        RetailItem item1 = new RetailItem("Jacket",12,59.95);
        RetailItem item2 = new RetailItem("Designer Jeans",40,34.95);
        RetailItem item3 = new RetailItem("Shirt",20,24.95);

        System.out.println("ItemNo.  Description     Quantity  Price");

        System.out.println("item1    " + item1.getDescription() + "          " + item1.getUnitsOnHand() + "        "  + item1.getPrice());

        System.out.println("item2    " + item2.getDescription() + "  " + item2.getUnitsOnHand() + "        "  + item2.getPrice());

        System.out.println("item3    " + item3.getDescription() + "           " + item3.getUnitsOnHand() + "        "  + item3.getPrice());

    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is then offer the user the option to close the program or add a new record, if they choose to add a new record I will use a switch statement and this is where my issue starts.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to add values to the 3 variables and then input them into a new object that increments each time.

i.e.

enter description, enter units, enter price

RetailItem item(increment+1) = new RetailItem(Var Des,Var Units, Var Price)

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Closed using a duplicate. The duplicate answer uses if and if/else statements instead of Switch, but you should get the general idea from it.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help